# MySQL Order By - IN

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(p_title), title
FROM
 `reg`
WHERE
 ( C_title REGEXP '[ENGINE]' or C_title REGEXP '[ENGINEER]')
 AND title IN ('Prof. Dr.','Dr.','Mr.')
```

or

```
    ORDER BY FIELD (title,'Prof. Dr.','Dr.')
```

I want to list only the Prof. Dr. and Dr. fields in my query. But first Prof's and second Dr's .... But, these codes are not functioning.

```
                    WHEN title = 'Prof. Dr.' THEN 1
                WHEN title = 'Assoc. Prof. Dr.' THEN 2
                WHEN title = 'Assist. Prof. Dr.' THEN 3
                WHEN title = 'Dr.' THEN 4
                WHEN title != 'Ms.' THEN 5
                WHEN title != 'Mr.' THEN 6
                ELSE 7
```

Could you tell me the alternative ways ?

Comment: Consider posting up a SQLFIDDLE, so we can see what your structure and content actually looks like.

Comment: Your case/when is the most common way I have done in the past, but is that all the "title" field contains is this leading component and not actually then name?  Do you want it alphabetized per name within each "Prof. Dr.", "Assoc. Prof. Dr.", etc?  Can you list some of the ACTUAL "title" values to help confirm your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [enumerated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html) field containing all the possible values, for better index performance, smaller data amount and better less errors (e.g. someone missing the dot after "Mr.",

What you are looking for are stacked if-statements:

```
SELECT title, IF('title' = 'Mr.', 1,
    IF (title = 'Mrs.', 2, 
        IF (title = 'Dr.', 3, 0)
    )
) 
AS title_number 
FROM users...
```

will return

```
title | title_number
--------------------
"Mr." | 1
"xxx" | 0
```

...